# Sorting/limiting the multidimensional associative array in PHP based on the number of repeated elements

Tags: php

I have a multi-dimensional array in PHP as follows:

```
$array = Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [bill] => 1 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [bill] => 1 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [bill] => 1 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [bill] => 1 )        
        [4] => Array ( [jack] => 5 ) 
        [5] => Array ( [jack] => 5 ) 
        [6] => Array ( [jake] => 6 ) 
        [7] => Array ( [jake] => 6 ) 
        [8] => Array ( [jake] => 6 ) 
        [9] => Array ( [jake] => 6 ) 
        [10] => Array ( [sara] => 7 ) 
        [11] => Array ( [sara] => 7 ) 
        [12] => Array ( [sara] => 7 ) 
        [13] => Array ( [sara] => 7 ) 
        [14] => Array ( [william] => 8 ) 
        [15] => Array ( [william] => 8 ) 
        [16] => Array ( [william] => 8 ) 
        [17] => Array ( [william] => 8 ) 
        [19] => Array ( [william] => 8 ) 
        [20] => Array ( [martin] => 9 ) 
        [21] => Array ( [martin] => 9 ) 
        [22] => Array ( [martin] => 9 ) 
        [23] => Array ( [tara] => 10 ) 
        [24] => Array ( [tara] => 10 ) 
        [25] => Array ( [tara] => 10 )              
        [26] => Array ( [tara] => 10 )              
      );
```

I want to convert `$array` to `$result` so that it can first sort the array based on the number of similar elements and then returning the first five values. For example, the `$array` has five similar `[william] => 8`, four similar `[bill] => 1`, four similar `[jake] => 6`, four similar `[sara] => 7`, four similar `[tara] => 10`, three similar `[martin] => 9` and two similar `[jack] => 5` in `$array` variable. So, the `$result` variable with the first five most repeated elements should be as follows:

```
$result = Array (
        [0] => Array ( [william] => 8 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [bill] => 1 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [jake] => 6 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [sara] => 7 ) 
        [4] => Array ( [tara] => 10 ) 
      );
```

Could you please help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: you cant control the source?

Comment: @Dagon, not really, I need to process the $array as it is in the question, any idea?

Comment: foreach loop, create new array, add as key(name) changes

Comment: @Dagon, Could you please submit your answer? thanks a lot,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new array that combines the keys and values and use `array_count_values` to count the # of occurrences. Finally sort and retrieve the top 5.

```
$new = array();      

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $new[] = key($value) . '_' . current($value);
}

$counts = array_count_values($new);
arsort($counts);
$results = array();

foreach(array_splice($counts,0,5) as $key => $count) {
    $key = explode('_',$key);
    $results[] = array($key[0] => $key[1]);
}

print_r($results);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = array();
$occurrence_map = array();
$pair_map = array();

foreach( $array as $record )
{
    $key = key($record);
    $pair_map[ $key ] = $record;
    ++$occurrence_map[ $key ];
}

while( 5 > count($result) && !empty($occurrence_map) )
{
    $related_key = '';
    $max_value = $occurrence_map[ key($occurrence_map) ];

    foreach( $occurrence_map as $key => $value )
    {
        if( $value > $max_value )
        {
            $max_value = $value;
            $related_key = $key;
        }
    }

    $result[] = $pair_map[$related_key];
    unset( $occurrence_map[$related_key] );
}
```

Result:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["william"]=>
    int(8)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["bill"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["jake"]=>
    int(6)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["sara"]=>
    int(7)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["tara"]=>
    int(10)
  }
}
```

Hope this help you.